# Where to find stdio.h functions implementations?

Tags: c

I study C and I noticed that I can't find the implementation file for some header files like, for example, `stdio.h` which is a library which contains a lot of input/output functions, like `printf`. Where can I find its implementation?

Comment: Usually you cannot have a look at implementations, that are part of the standard C-code (and all standard headers are part of the standard C-code).

Comment: @AudioDroid Why is that? Does ANSI have a copyright of the implementation? Or is it just that the source code implementation has never been distributed?

Someone somewhere MUST have the source right?

Comment: @Minh Tran As you can read below, I am actually not right about this. There is open-source implementations that you can look at. But otherwise, e.g. using the MS C-compiler, yes, they have the rights to their own implementation. The standard just defines how it needs to work, not how to implement it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Download one of these:

- [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/)
- [uclibc](http://www.uclibc.org/)
- [dietlibc](http://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/)
- [BSD libc](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/lib/libc/)

Or, even better, download several of these and compare their implementations. Of course, these are likely doing a lot of things different compared to *your* particular standard library implementation, but would still be quite interesting for e.g. non-platform-specific functionality such as sprintf.

Answer (score 9):

You need to find the source code for a C standard library like glibc: http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/

You can download the source here: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/
It contains source for all the library functions.

Comment: I see. the implementation of functions are build in library. Right ?

Answer (score 7):

For example [here](http://www.jbox.dk/sanos/source/lib/stdio.c.html). Google is your friend - just search for `stdio.c`. But note that you should handle these as "one implementation of many possible" - you don't know how your compiler is doing it by reading those, you just get an idea of how it can be done.

Answer (score 6):

On Ubuntu or other OS that uses aptitude for package management, you can use:

```
apt-get source libc6
```

for example.

Also, running gcc in verbose mode will tell you the details of the paths it is using. This should help you find which include and library paths it's using.

```
gcc -v
```

or

```
gcc -Wl,--verbose
```

Answer (score 4):

If you install the Windows SDK, there is an option to include the standard library source code, so you can also see how it is implemented on Windows.