# Where to find the implementation of stdio.h?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to find stdio.h functions implementations ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233514/where-to-find-stdio-h-functions-implementations)

Hi, I am trying to find the function definitions of the functions defined in stdio.h header file, I want to learn how functions like printf() is achieved, but I can't find any preprocessor directives link in stdio.h to the implementation file elsewhere. How can a C Compiler know where to find the implementations when there are no direct references to the function definition file? (I learned that .h file may accompany with a same name .c implementation file from an objective-c book.) Could you help me? Thanks! I am using GCC on Mac OS X.

Comment: A "header" need not be a file at all. A compiler can actually have it all built in.

Comment: Since you haven't specified which compiler you're using, you can see Microsoft's implementation if you have a non-express version of Visual Studio AFAIK.  They are typically found in: `\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio [ver no.]\VC\crt`

Answer (score 8):

`FreeBSD`'s libc is pretty well laid out in its src repository.

http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/lib/libc/

e.g. for `printf(3)`:

http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/lib/libc/stdio/printf.c?view=markup

http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/lib/libc/stdio/vfprintf.c?view=markup

Comment: +1 for FreeBSD's refreshingly sane source tree

Comment: You might want to link to `vfprintf()` as well since thats the function that does all the heavy lifting - parsing the actual arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Try downloading source code for [GLIBC](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/) library project. That's where definitions for standard functions are when using GCC compiler (and derivates).

Comment: `gcc` doesn't have to use `glibc`.  But if you're running a typical Linux distro then you'll most likely be using it.