# Library functions - where can i find them

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to find stdio.h functions implementations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233514/where-to-find-stdio-h-functions-implementations)

In C i have been using headers that contain prototypes and declarations of functions provided by the libraries, but where are functions like `printf`, `scanf`, etc. stored?

Where are they stored?

In which directory?

Why can't i find them? Are they stored as object files?

Comment: Are you looking for the declaration, source code, or executable code, of these library functions?

Comment: I am not looking for source code. I want to know if these are stored as object files or executables, whichever be the case - where are they stored?

Comment: The actual library implementations are stored in shared library files which are linked against your programs and loaded by the OS at runtime. The standard C library functions like printf are stored in /lib/libc.so on Linux/BSD and  c:\windows\system32\msvcrt.dll on Windows. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

As everyone said, its int `libc`. You can search google for source code browser for the OS you are interested in, for linux I could find: http://lxr.linux.no/linux/

For `netbsd`, you can find `printf` and `scanf` here:
http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libc/?only_with_tag=MAIN#dirlist

Comment: On many Unix-like systems, the math functions are in `libm`, not `libc`.  (This causes a lot of confusion, since the linker can't find `sqrt()`, for example, unless you explicitly invoke the linker or compiler with `-lm`.)

Comment: @Keith Thompson: Thanks kaith. You are right but I, probably, am not getting your point here. What are you trying to convey?

Comment: Just that the code that implements the math functions is often in libm, not in libc.  (More precisely, in /usr/lib/libm.so, not /usr/lib/libc.so, or some other system-specific naming convention.)

Comment: @Keith Thompson: Agree. I never mentioned anything about math functions. I just wanted to show OP a way by searching in code browsers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These functions are provided by the standard C library, often called libc.

In linux, you can find it under `/lib/libc.so`
In Windows they call it [C Run-Time Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

One place to check out is the [**`section 3 of the manual`**](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/dir_section_3.html). Then each individual function manual page lists the required header files and what additional libraries, if any, you need to link with.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X, those functions are in `stdio.h` and is located in `/usr/include`. The library `libc.dylib` is in `/usr/lib`.

Comment: `libc.dylib` is a symbolic link to the actual system library on OS X - `libSystem.dylib`.